# Trouble with regular expressions parser

Tags: .net, regex, string

Im trying to create a method that checks a string against a regular express and returns a register type(mips). The problem is that I can't seem to be able to create the correct regex.
Please take a look and make suggestions. Thanks

```
 public static RegisterType CheckRegex(this string source)
        {
            var tempMatch = new Regex("$t0|$t1|$t2|$t3|$t4|$t5|$t6|$t7|$t8|$t9|").Match(source);  //$t0 - $t9
            if(tempMatch.Length == source.Length)
                return RegisterType.Temporary;
            var storeMatch = new Regex(@"(^\$s)+[0-9]").Match(source);  //$s0 - $s9
            if (storeMatch.Length == source.Length)
                return RegisterType.Store;
            var reservedMatch = new Regex(@"").Match(source);            //$k0 - $k1
            if (reservedMatch.Length == source.Length)
                return RegisterType.OSReserved;
            var constantMatch = new Regex(@"0-9").Match(source);        //Any integer
            if (constantMatch.Length == source.Length)
                return RegisterType.Constant;
            var memoryMatch = new Regex("").Match(source);
            if (memoryMatch.Length == source.Length)
                return RegisterType.Memory;

            return RegisterType.Invalid;
        }
```

UPDATE: Everything is working now ,excluding my Memory Regex

```
public static RegisterType GetRegisterType(this string source)
        {
            if (Regex.IsMatch(source, @"\$t[0-9]"))
                return RegisterType.Temporary; // $t0 - $t9
            if (Regex.IsMatch(source, @"\$s[0-9]"))
                return RegisterType.Store; // $s0 - $s9
            if (Regex.IsMatch(source, @"\$k[0-1]"))
                return RegisterType.OSReserved; // $k0 - $k1
            if (Regex.IsMatch(source, @"[-+]?\b\d+\b"))
                return RegisterType.Constant;
            if (Regex.IsMatch(source, @"\$zero"))
                return RegisterType.Special;
            if (Regex.IsMatch(source, @"[a-zA-Z0-9]+\b\:"))
                return RegisterType.Label;
            if (Regex.IsMatch(source, @"\d+\b\(\$[s-t]\b[0-9])"))
                return RegisterType.Memory;
            return RegisterType.Invalid;

        }
```

Comment: What part is going wrong? Where are you not matching. Note, I believe you need to escape the `$` in the temporary register match expression

Comment: I have a further question (as it has been years since I was writing MIPS assembly), is your source a full instruction? Your expression for matching the k registers is blank? Your expression for matching "memory" is also a blank regex. Can you give some `source` examples?

Comment: @pstrjds In reference to memory ex: lw $t7,248($t2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have said, you need to escape the dollar signs in `"$t0|$t1|$t2|$t3|$t4|$t5|$t6|$t7|$t8|$t9|"` by prefixing them with a backslash.  Also, you can write that more concisely as `@"\$t[0-9]"`.  That will match a dollar sign followed by `'t'` followed by a single digit.  You've got a trailing pipe character followed by nothing, as well, that can be removed.

Comment: In fact, the trailing `|` *must* be removed.  With it there, the regex can legitimately match nothing, just as if you had wrapped it in in parentheses and added the `?` quantifier.  That means the first test will always succeed and none of the others will be performed.  Your concise version also corrects that error.

Answer (score 3):

`$` is a special character in regular expression, matches at the end of the line. If you want to match `$` literal, use escaping `(\$)`

Answer (score 1):

If your `source` is just a register/memory location, you could probably simplify this thing down to something like this:

```
public static RegisterType CheckRegex(this string source)
{
    if (Regex.IsMatch(@"\$\t\d")) return RegisterType.Temporary; // $t0 - $t9
    if (Regex.IsMatch(@"\$\s\d")) return RegisterType.Store; // $s0 - $s9
    if (Regex.IsMatch(@"\$\k\[0-1]")) return RegisterType.OSReserved; // $k0 - $k1
    if (Regex.IsMatch(source, @"\d")) return RegisterType.Constant;
    // Don't remember the pattern for Memory, if you post an update I can update this

    return RegisterType.Invalid;
}
```